# Validar nombre de usuario dentro de un filechooser o desde otra ventana que envie al filechooser

Tags: eclipse, ssh

Cómo puedo guardar el nombre de usuario para que dicho usuario cuando autentique le pueda abrir la ventana de un jfilechooser y pueda hacer carga de archivos, dicho nombre se tiene que guardar para que pueda conectarse vía ssh.

```
//SSH VIA RSYNC
    rsync.setOptions(new String[]{"-avz","-e","ssh",path,"(VA NOMBRE DEL USUARIO QUE SE CONECTE)@192.168.2.219:rsync"});
```

Comment: que lenguaje es eso?

Comment: Estoy en eclipse, te dejo el link de información https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2170-que-es-rsync-y-como-usarlo-para-respaldos/